# Run webpage C# function on visitors CPU?

Tags: c#, javascript, performance, loops

What is a good way to run a time-consuming function from a C# webpage on the users CPU instead of running it on the web-server? Is it possible to get a C# function to run locally or do I have to write the function in JavaScript? The function itself is not secret in any way but I would prefer if the input and the output will be kept secret from the user. The solution should not require the user to download anything.

This functions uses data from the database + user input and when it's finished it writes the output to the database.

The functions best case is ~1s, average ~30s and worst ~10min (for every user) so it's not an option to run this function on the web-server.

Comment: You will NEVER be able to keep something secret if you process it on the client.

Comment: I'd look into improving the function's performance.

Comment: Your question shows a complete and total lack of understanding of how the web works.  Javascript would run on the client side.  Many of the scripting languages would, ASP.NET and C# would not, Java Web Application would.  Silverlight would.  What you want to do makes no sense, the communication with the database MUST be done te server side, so you gain NOTHING by attempting to do what you want to do.

Comment: I would prefer to keep it secret, but it is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* get this to work, by either

- coding the function in JavaScript
- compiling the C# source to JavaScript (off the beaten track)
- running the C# code in silverlight (done and done again, remember Java Applets? same science)

You won't really be able to keep the data totally secret, though.

Now, how to go about this... You will need a web service to provide the data to your silverlight component and another one to accept the computed results. You know, I don't really see why everyone else here thinks this is such a no-go...

As for data secrecy... The best you can do is obfuscate, though you *should* use a secure communication layer for *aquiring* the data and *posting* the results back, what ends up on the users computer will eventually be open for inspection by the user. If you use obfuscation techniques for your code, this will make reverse engineering an encryption/decryption scheme for the data payload harder, but you're playing essentially the same game as game devs / game crackers...

Personally, I would code the client side stuff in JavaScript. Chances are, what you want done is more of an algorithmic thing than a library thing, so porting to js should not be difficult to pull off.

Comment: Just hope the user doesn't close their browser or move to a different page for ~10 minutes.

Comment: depends a little on the page - and on your computation scheme. you *should* tell the user what you are doing. and the user *needs* to buy into why you are doing this. say, image processing of his pics - he wants it, so he should pay for it in cpu dollars, right?

Comment: It works well to create a <input type="hidden"> and run a JavaScript that stores a value in the <input> and then run a Submit so that the page is reloaded. When the page is loading I can read the value inside the <input> (with C# code) and add it to the database. Maybe not the best way, but it works.

The user has made ​​an active choice to run the function and want to see the results when completed. The user will provide their own input and the better the input, the less time it takes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't and shouldn't run arbitrary cs code on the user's computer. You also can't really run a long lived process in javascript on the client. User interaction with the page will be blocked and if they navigate to a different page it will stop.

What you should do is write a windows service to run these tasks in the background. Have a queue table where you save the input data from the web side, then have a service that polls the table for work and processes the input data.

Comment: unless youre like SETI, with the explicit goal of offloading work to the client for scaling purposes?

Comment: Obviously if you can get the client to install a program you can get them to run code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute any C# code on the client computer when you they enter a webpage. You are correct in your assumption that you need to write it in javascript to execute it on the client.

Comment: unless you have a silverlight thingy?

Comment: While possible, that seems like a bad idea. What if the user closes the browser or moves to another page in the ~10 minutes the process takes?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work. Web server does the processing. Unless you are doing distributed computing and stuff like that, it is not designed to work on a client. Client needs to download software to process stuff. Webpage is webpage. Text.

Answer (score 0):

The only code you can run on the client is js.
That being said, you definitely don't want to run your function on the client if you have sensitive information involved.